# Residue of $\frac{1}{(e^z-e)^3}$ at $z = 1$

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus

I'm trying to calculate the residue of $\dfrac{1}{(e^z-e)^3}$ at $z = 1$. The answer is $\dfrac{1}{e^3}$, but having trouble seeing how one would arrive at that. Any hints?

Comment: Do you know how to generally find residues?

Comment: As an alternative to the other answers, it's easy to see that $1$ is a pole of order $3$, thus its residue is given by $$\dfrac{1}{(3-1)!}\lim \limits_{z\to 0}\left[\dfrac{d^2}{dz^2}\left(z\mapsto \dfrac{(z-1)^3}{(e^z-e)^3}\right)(z)\right]$$ and [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=limit+as+z+approaches+1+d%5E2%2Fdz%5E2+%28z-1%29%5E3%2F%28e%5Ez-e%29%5E3+) confirms it.

Comment: Yes, I know the general formula. I tried to differentiate twice but that approach seems to make calculations too tedious to be the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $z=1+u$ and $u\to0$, then $f(z)=(\mathrm e^z-\mathrm e)^{-3}=\mathrm e^{-3}(\mathrm e^u-1)^{-3}$, that is, $f(z)=\mathrm e^{-3}u^{-3}g(u)$ with $g(u)=(1+\frac12u+\frac16u^2+o(u^2))^{-3}$.

Since $(1+v)^{-3}=1-3v+6v^2+o(v^2)$ when $v\to0$, this implies that $$
g(u)=1-\tfrac32u-\tfrac12u^2+6\left(\tfrac12u\right)^2+o(u^2),
$$
that is, 
$$f(z)=\mathrm e^{-3}(u^{-3}-\tfrac32u^{-2}+u^{-1}+o(u^{-1})).
$$
In particular the residue of the function $f$ at $z=1$ is the coefficient of $u^{-1}$ in its Laurent expansion, that is, $\mathrm e^{-3}\cdot1$.